# Datalake database in sink synapse pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

We have a blockage on a synapse pipeline, we want to create a sink on a lake database from a workflow. But impossible to select the lake database created, only the default is displayed. I looked on some forums but  I do not find much and they say that it is in development at Microsot.Do you have an idea please?

Comment: publish your lake database then try again, after successfully publishing lake database it will be visible in Workspace Db under database.

Comment: yes, i dot it, commit and push in git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posting it as answer for other community members.

First publish your lake database to the azure synapse and then try to add it in your sink on pipeline.

As in below image Database 1 is created and published and it is getting displayed in Sink Database and Database 2 is created but not published hence it is not getting displayed in Sink Database.
[image]

Comment: and when I add a table name in the sink it automatically adds it to the database ? i add it but it not work, it work just for the default database

Comment: no it will show only tables available in selected database.